# Success but doesnt insert to Database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

it says success but it doesnt really insert the values to Database. idk whats going on.

```
if($_POST['submit']){

$registerQuery = 'INSERT INTO `user`(firstname`, `lastname`, `email_address`, `password`, `mobile_number`,`location`) VALUES (
"'.$firstname.'",
"'.md5($password).'",
"'.$lastname.'",
"'.$emailaddress.'",
"'.$password.'",
"'.$mobile_number.'",
"'.$location.'");';
echo 'Success';
}
$qry = mysql_query($registerQuery);
```

Comment: You always echo 'Success', that's why it always shows that message. You might want to take a look at the [mysql_query documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-query.php) and check for the return value.

Comment: also, you have a syntax error ... check your tick-marks ... especially around firstname ...

Comment: If possible you try and use the mysqli version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because there are 7 values and 6 columns and you miss a backtick around the `firstname` column. The number of values and columns must be the same. You always echo `Success` because you don't check if `$qry` is `false` (it returns false on error). Finally, you should not use `mysql_*` functions because they are officially deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Use either PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: True, but also missing a tick `\`` around the `firstname` column name.

Answer (score 2):

Your echo statement is not wrapped in a conditional, and runs before the query is executed. As a result "Success" will be echoed no matter what.

Instead, you want to check the response of `mysql_query` to see whether it executed successfully, then take action (like echoing 'Success') based on that result.

`mysql_query()` always returns `false` on error, so you can check `$qry` to see if it is false:

```
if ($qry === false) {
    echo "Query failed";
    // take action as needed
}
else {
    echo "Success";
    // take action as needed
}
```

To see the exact error that caused the failure, use `mysql_error()`. You can execute this in the 'failed' section of code, above.

In this case, the failure was caused by two errors in your query:

**Syntax**

There is a missing backtick before 'firstname':

```
'INSERT INTO `user`(firstname`,
```

should be

```
'INSERT INTO `user`(`firstname`,
```

**Column/Value Count Mismatch**

Your query specifies that six columns will be filled:

```
(`firstname`, `lastname`, `email_address`, `password`, `mobile_number`,`location`)
```

but seven values were provided:

```
"'.$firstname.'",
"'.md5($password).'",
"'.$lastname.'",
"'.$emailaddress.'",
"'.$password.'",
"'.$mobile_number.'",
"'.$location.'");'
```

**Deprecation Warning**

Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated; they have been replaced by PDO. Consider for safety and stability, consider modifying your code to use PDO.

Comment: You could also use `mysqli_*`. The difference between `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` isn't much. You can also use `mysqli_*` with OOP so maybe starting with `mysqli_*` is better as it is easier. PDO is more for OOP

Comment: The `mysqli_*` functions are an improvement over `mysql_*`. For someone familiar with the `mysql_*` functions and unwilling to learn something new, they can be a near-drop-in replacement. However, PDO has many advantages, including its abstraction layer and easy SQL-injection protection via prepared statements. If the code is going to be refactored anyway, one may was well take advantage of the best available technology.

Answer (score 0):

you are also missing a back-tick surrounding firstname...

should be:

```
$registerQuery = 'INSERT INTO `user`(`firstname`, `lastname`
```